# QEvent::TouchBegin event only contains 1 touchpoint during multi-point gesture on Windows 8 tablet

Tags: c++, windows, qt, tablet

I am developing a QT-based application (QT 5.2) for Windows 8 tablets. I would like to provide multi-touch and mouse support to move, zoom and translate images displayed within the widget. My problem is highlighted with the following overridden event() function:

```
bool myWidget::event(QEvent *e)
{
  switch(e->type())
  {
    case QEvent::TouchBegin:
    {
        QTouchEvent *touchEvent = static_cast<QTouchEvent *>(e);
        QList<QTouchEvent::TouchPoint> touchPoints = touchEvent->touchPoints();
        if (touchPoints.count() == 1) 
           std::cout << "Only 1 touch" << std::endl;
        else
           std::cout << "More than 1 touch" << std::endl; 
    }
    default: 
      return QWidget::event(e);
  }
  return true;
}
```

Regardless of how many fingers are used to touch the screen, the TouchBegin event only ever contains 1 touchPoint. How can I distinguish between a single finger gesture and a multiple finger gesture if the initial TouchBegin event only contains 1 touchPoint? Furthermore, the overridden mousePressEvent is also sent an event when multiple fingers touch the surface making it even more difficult to parse.

Any advice?

Comment: What happens in subsequent touch events? Is it still one touch point, or more? How do you know that the underlying platform (Windows) behaves the way you expect? Do you have any native Windows testcases that demonstrate the behavior you expect? Only then I'd consider it a Qt bug.